# Error selenium, java, appium para pruebas mobile

Tags: selenium-webdriver

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   'org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory.createDefault()'

Al tratar de ejecutar la prueba me aparece este error, tengo corriendo la appium y el emulador mediante el avd

Comment: te faltan jars donde esta ese metodo

Comment: Hola @abrahamhs gracias por tu respuesta, cuales serian esos jar que me faltan? en principio le añadi al classpath guava, okhttp, okio, byte-buddy, commons-exec, java-client, server standalone, y los 2 clientes..

Answer (score 0):

Te faltan jars. [Esta es la dependencia](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver/3.12.0/source-code/org/openqa/selenium/remote/http/HttpClient.java):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```